# Post rollbacks with optional reason

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks

Quite often I find myself rolling back changes where I need to explain why I've done the rollback.

For example,

- someone adds inflammatory remarks to a post after receiving downvotes
- OP adds edits or follow-ups after accepting an answer
- an answer is edited introducing typos or incorrect information
- someone makes a change that conflicts with the author's intent

For these reasons and more, a rollback is definitely what is required, but rolling back without context often leads to rollback wars.

Here would be the default rollback message:

> Rollback to Revision 1

Here would be a rollback message with a reason, if the feature is implemented:

> Rollback to Revision 1. Reason: edit introduces off-topic comments

I'm not sure on the exact mechanics of how such a field should be shown, but it should probably be done without introducing an extra click if not needed (meaning a user interacts with this field/dialog only if they need to add a reason).

Now existing solutions are to either

1. rollback and leave a comment explaining why and hope no one slings mud at you
2. copy the revision source and edit the answer yourself with an edit reason "Rolling back to revision #x because blah"

Neither of these options are as simple as leaving a reason while clicking the rollback button. Adding a message would also make your intention clear to moderators or others trying to resolve a dispute.

Thoughts?

Comment: "[This feature already exists!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41954/398364)"

Comment: @Ivar Huh, kinda cumbersome but that is a legitimate workaround. (inb4 feature request to hammer uber meta dupe.)

Comment: Don't need that feature; I found a dupe on this Meta. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems this is a dupe of an [uber meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41953/494004) from way back when. This feature already exists and you can trigger it with the following steps (from [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41954/494004)):

1. Open up the revision history on the post you wish to roll back.
2. Click "edit" on the revision you wish to roll back to.
3. Type your reason for rolling back into the "Edit Summary" field.